# Service Now attachment download through powershell scripting

Tags: xml, powershell, soap, wsdl, servicenow

I am trying to automate downloading attachment from the ServiceNow ticket(Incident) using scripts. The attached file will have data for another script to excute.

Inputs are Incident Number. From that, I'm able to fetch Sys_Id, Sys_attachment_doc and sys_attachment.do tables's sys_id also using SOAP. From the SOAP response, I'm not able to get the Raw data. We don't prefer handling Chunks and decoding.

I'm trying to use

```
"Downloading [$url]`nSaving at [$path]" 
    $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
    $client.DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

and Also, I tried with Invoke-webrequest also, but to no avail.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://sampleorganization.service-now.com/sys_attachment.do?xml&sys_id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa23bbbbb" -OutFile "C:\attachemnts.csv"
```

That gives me an HTML file that I do not want.

Manually, I was able to download the attachment by using

```
"https://sampleorganization.service-now.com/sys_attachment.do?xml&sys_id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa23bbbbb" and clicking "Save"
```

I would like to directly download the attachment from Ticket without any confirmation passed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use browser dev tools to see what request is submitted so you can emulate that behavior.

Comment: Tried a couple of different methods on my org's SN instance against an incident that had an Excel workbook attached. When I output my results to a plain text file, it looks like it was a rather lengthy bunch of javascript from the Glide API making internal calls to wherever the file is stored internally. I'm not too familiar with how the guts of Service Now work, but that seemed to be part of what keeps this from being simple